# Exception while running Quartz Scheduler program

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am getting he following Exception while running my Quartz Schdular program.

Below is the exception Trace

```
Mar 26, 2010 2:54:24 PM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler start
INFO: Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Job class must implement the Job interface.
    at org.quartz.JobDetail.setJobClass(JobDetail.java:291)
    at org.quartz.JobDetail.<init>(JobDetail.java:138)
    at com.Quarrtz.RanchSchedule.main(RanchSchedule.java:18)
```

I have included `Quartz-1.7.2.jar` and 
`Quartz-all-1.7.2.jar` in my class path along with `commom-logging 1.1.jar` and jdk 6

this is an example i have copy and pasted from [JavaRanch][1]

First example in the above page

```
public interface Job {

    void execute (JobExecutionContext ctx);
}
```

---

```
public class RanchJob implements Job {

    public void execute (JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("[JOB] Welcome at JavaRanch");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RanchSchedule {

    public static void main (String[] args) {       
        try {
            SchedulerFactory factory = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();

            Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();

            JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("ranchJob", null, RanchJob.class);
            // Fires every 10 seconds
            Trigger ranchTrigger = TriggerUtils.makeSecondlyTrigger(10); 
            ranchTrigger.setName("ranchTrigger");

            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, ranchTrigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you written the Job interface in your source code ?

```
public interface Job {
    void execute (JobExecutionContext ctx);
}
```

If so, you don't have to do this. Quartz has its own Job interface (in the quartz.jar).
Keep only your RanchJob and RanchSchedule classes and it should work.